# How to align bottom edge to Center of above view swiftui

Tags: swiftui, uiimageview, gradient, center, yaxis

I'm currently trying to align the person image vertical center (/centerY) to the bottom edge of the gradient view in a SwiftUI View.

Code:-

```
struct GroupDetailScreen: View {
var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        VStack {
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.red,Color.blue]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                .frame(width:UIScreen.screenWidth,height: 180, alignment: .center)
                .clipped()
            ZStack{
                Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
                    .renderingMode(.original)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Output**

[image: Screenshot]

**Want to achieve:-**

[image: Screenshot]

Can someone please explain to me how to align the person image vertical center (/centerY) to the bottom edge of the gradient view. I've tried to implement by above but no results yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are several ways to do this.

And I used this way with `overlay` and `offset` here.

```
struct GroupDetailScreen: View {
var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        VStack {
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.red,Color.blue]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 180, alignment: .center)
                .clipped()
                .overlay(
                    Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
                        .renderingMode(.original)
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .offset(y: 90) // 1/2 of view height (180*(1/2)
                )
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) // for ignore safe area
            
            Spacer()
         }
      }
   }
}
```

---

[image]